# Gekko PRED_HOR and CTRL_HOR vs m.time

Tags: gekko

I'm trying to implement an online MPC controller and I'm a bit confused about what exactly the m.time does.

With `m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC` and `m.options.REQCTRLMODE=3`, I try to define the prediction and control horizons:

```
m.options.CTRL_HOR=10
m.options.CTRL_TIME=0.05
m.options.PRED_HOR=10
m.options.PRED_TIME=0.05
```

If I understand it right the `ctrl_hor` and `pred_hor` sets how many future timesteps we calculate and the `pred_time` and `ctrl_time` defines how long is one timestep.
But the problem is that the controller throws an error if I don't define `m.time`, but what exactly does it do and why isn't it enough to set ctrl and pred horizons with respective timesteps?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please strongly consider posting a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of both HTML and CSS (and JS if applicable or other lang.) so we can better help you thank you. Also, please focus on a single specific question.

Comment: Here is another recent post on Control and Prediction horizons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040582/the-control-horizon-and-prediction-horizon/64046894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gekko uses `m.time` by default instead of `CTRL_HOR` and `PRED_HOR`. You can define an equivalent control / prediction horizon in Gekko with:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,0.05,11)
```

The `CTRL_HOR` and `PRED_HOR` properties are optionally used when `CSV_READ=0`. However, Gekko uses the CSV file to insert information about default values for parameters and variables so I don't recommend that you turn it off. Using `m.time` is also more flexible because you can have a non-uniform control / prediction horizon such as:

```py
m.time = [0,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1.0]
```

This helps to have the fine resolution at the beginning and then larger steps to determine steady-state move plans. Here is a [practical TCLab MPC application](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF) with real-time data.

[image: MPC Application]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suspected that that's what the m.time does, but what can I do if I need prediction and control horizons to be different from each other?

Comment: You can set up something like `m.time = [0.0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.4,0.6.0.8,1.0]` that is equivalent to `CTRL_TIME=0.05`, `CTRL_HOR=4`, `PRED_TIME=0.2`, `PRED_HOR=8`. If you really don't want to adjust the last 4 moves of the MV prediction horizon then you can use `m.Connection()` to connect them into a single value.